# How to deploy an Azure Web App Application Insights extension multiple times using ARM

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template

I have an ARM template which deploys multiple web apps. Since they don’t depend on each other they are deployed in parallel. Each of the web apps need to install the Application Insights sideextension using the following template:

```
{
                    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                    "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites",
                    "type": "siteextensions",
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webappname'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {}
                }
```

This however leeds to conflict errors since the name of the deployment is identical each time. 1 succeeds, 4 fail. If I run it again, 1 succeeds, 3 fail. Is there a way around this issue? Or do I need to stop deploying the web apps in parallel?

Complete error:

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "Conflict",
      "message": "{\r\n  \"Message\": \"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites\"\r\n}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the complete Web App template. This is called multiple times in parallel as a linked template to create multiple web apps.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "serverfarmName": {
            "type": "string"
        },"applicationInsightsName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "webappname": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "name": "[parameters('webappname')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('serverfarmName'))]"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "name": "appsettings",
                    "type": "config",
                    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webappname'))]",
                        "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('applicationInsightsName')), '2014-04-01').InstrumentationKey]",
                        "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~2",
                        "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode": "recommended",
                        "InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~1",
                        "DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3",
                        "APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION": "1.0.0",
                        "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions": "~1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
                    "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites",
                    "type": "siteextensions",
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('webappname'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {}
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "webappName": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('webappname')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt make a lot of sense, unfortunately, can you share the whole template?

Comment: Added the template. As stated, this is called multiple times in parallel as a linked template. Therefor the name exists multiple times in the same deployment leading to a conflict.

Comment: this doesnt make sense either, unfortunately. your proposition that this fails due to the same name is wrong, because its not same. easiest way to test this is to switch to paralell invocation with: `"mode": "serila", "batchSize": 1`, when you invoke it. reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#resource-iteration

Comment: As I said before, if I make sure these are not deployed at the same time it works. Why is my assumption wrong? The name is the same, its always "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AzureWebSites"

Comment: because name defines the resource uniquely, if it works in parallel means the names are different (name is a part of resource id), they get the part of the resource id from the parent resource. if the names (resourceids) would be identical then you'd overwrite the same resource over and over again. unless you give a complete repro I'm unable to figure this out. this looks absolutely valid

Comment: It does not override because the deployments happen at the same time, triggerd nearly at the same second. Therefor the conflict error and not an override.

Comment: ok, you clearly know better than I do, why ask the question than?

Comment: The question is: is there a way to make an siteextension deployment unique. As your said, name defines the resource uniquely and this is exactly the problem here.

Comment: no, that is not the problem here, resourceid is unique already

Comment: @E.Staal Why are you not using the Insights template instead of siteextension? Is there a reason? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/allversions

Comment: Well, simply forgot about that one. Will give it a try!